# Shortest way to write 787 in an arithmetic expression?

Tags: number-theory

I need some help on this because I can't figure it out.

Given only +, -, /, * (arithmetic operations) and the value x where x > 0,  Is there a way to write 787 with at most 28 arithmetic operations?

Best I could come up with is 29 operations with a dynamic programming code (i can post it here upon request). I know that it can be <= 28 because it comes from a programming competition problem. So, my assumption is that I'm lacking something with the code.

Answers for first few values for better understanding:

```
0: xx-     ops = 1
1: xx/     ops = 1
2: xx+x/   ops = 2
3: xxx++x/ ops = 3
```

The above table is in postfix, but can easily be infix. Fixation doesn't matter. The number before the colon is the goal value, the expression evaluates to that goal value and the `ops` value is the number of operations in the expression.

Comment: You allude to a programming competition as the source of this problem and refer to it as demonstrating the possibility of doing better than you were able.  Is there a nexus with a mathematical investigation?

Comment: do you want exactly 28 operations?

Comment: @Ante At most 28. Edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar sequence is https://oeis.org/A005245, where they use $1$s and just addition and multiplication.  They count the number of $1$s, which I think should be no less than yours because they don't need to divide by $x$ at the end.

In that sequence, they seem to be working with 
$$787=2\cdot 3(2\cdot 5 \cdot (4 \cdot 3 +1)+1)+1$$
which needs $22\ 1$s.  As that has $22$ operands and $5$ multiplies it should take $28$ operators.

Comment: I tried that idea. But when you replace 1 with x, the multiplications squares the x. So you don't get the same result. Would be nice if there was a similar sequence involving arbitrary x's.

Comment: Also, your expression doesn't seem balanced?

Comment: @Mercado:  yes, I realized later that multiplies cost you more than adds for that reason.  I updated the formula to remove one multiply and now it matches the one you gave in the last comment.

Comment: But it evaluates to 781

Comment: @Mercado:  I lost one $+1$.  Now updated.

Comment: Here is 27 operations: `((x+x)/x*(x+x+x)*(((x+x)/x*(x+x+x+x+x)*(((x+x+x+x)/x*(x+x+x)+x)/x)+x)/x)+x)/x`
I replaced the constants with (x+x...)/x, then I distributed the common division between addends.

Answer (score 0):

With Ross Millikan's answer, I replaced the constants with (x+x+..)/x then distruted the common divisions between addends to reduce the operations. I got this:
`((x+x)/x*(x+x+x)*(((x+x)/x*(x+x+x+x+x)*(((x+x+x+x)/x*(x+x+x)+x)/x)+x)/x)+x)/x` which has 27 operations.

So I guess, what's missing in my DP is the ability to cancel out common division.

For future reference, I wrote code to generate the minimum expression needed to build Y. Here: https://github.com/mightymercado/icpc-solutions/blob/master/2016-regionals-manila/E.cpp